# htaccess redirecting to url.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted the following url `www.example.com/userprofile.php?username=username`
To `www.example.com/username`

Below is my htaccess file

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1index [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1login [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ userprofile.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

When i type `www.example.com/username` the GET username is echoed as

```
username.php
```

I've tried everything but can't get a solution 
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> When I type `www.example.com/username` the GET username is echoed as `username.php`

Because you have a rewrite earlier in the file:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

that rewrites `/username` (any request that does not map to an existing file) to `/username.php` *before* rewriting this to `userprofile.php?username=username.php`. Hence why you see the GET param value with a `.php` suffix.

Likewise, the following two `RewriteRule` directives aren't doing anything currently, since the earlier rule is catching the request.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1index [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1login [NC,L]
> ```

And these would only conflict with the "username" rewrite, if we modify the preceding rewrite to append the `.php` extension. But also, these two rules conflict with each other - you are matching the same URL with both - the first rule would always win. (One input, with two different outputs is just not possible in any scenario.) In fact, this will likely generate a rewrite loop.

These two directives should be removed.

---

To avoid `.php` being appended to `username`, you could check that the `.php` file exists *before* rewriting to it. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

However, I would also consider changing your URL structure so you can easily target URLs that are specifically stating a username. For example:

```
www.example.com/u/username
```

Then your directive can be written less ambiguously (and wouldn't be so dependent on the ordering of directives in your file):

```
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ userprofile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also, be more specific in the regex that captures the username. The pattern `.*` captures *anything*. For example, if usernames can only contain the letters a..z then use a regex like `^u/([a-z]+)$`. And if usernames must be 4 or more characters then: `^u/([a-z]{4,})$`.